# ASP.NET MVC2 slow after re-compilation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-2, debug-symbols

My ASP.NET MVC2 app took very long before serving first request, if I recompile just 1 file in 1 project. I have compiled in Release mode, disabled IntelliTrace and even do not load debug symbols, still SLOW !

My solution contains 7 projects, even if I just compile 1 file and reload the site, it took an whooping 53 seconds to reload. Imagine in a day I need to compile/recompile 60 times, I've wasted almost 1 hour.

Is there anybody experience the same ? Any suggestion or direction to look at ?

link to screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCfAL.png
[image: See the log timestamp : it took 53 seconds after recompilation to reload the web]

Comment: When you deploy a site, IIS has to recompile the views as well as restart the application.  By changing even one file in one project, the entire app will recompile and you will suffer a performance hit on each reload.  I will agree 60 seconds seems excessive, but it really depends on how large your project is (deploying msdn.microsoft.com would probably take awhile to restart) as well as how much you have your code doing on application startup.  Are you using EF?  The first hit to an EF site, if not done properly can take a long time generating the metadata for the models, etc.

Comment: No I do not use EF. Plus 53 seconds is the time needed for my request to hit global.asax.cs_Application_Start() method, it is not even the time to response yet.

The attachment is the screenshot of my log: the highlighted line is the time I complete re-build, and the line after is the time when the request hit global.asax.cs ! The difference is 53s.

What can we do shorten first hit performance hit ? FYI I'm already on SSD /w SATA3, CPU i7 4700MQ with 16GB RAM so I guess not the hardware issue.

Comment: I'm using NHibernate btw. 

My initial finding : the page reload is slow because we have lots of  HTML DOM entities to be inserted on page load. 

Any suggestion to fasten this process ? FYI the HTML DOM entities collection is huge (10,000s items), but they are quite static. 

Should we cache the whole page ? Especially the homepage ?